# Velociculture viability (Los Raptors Hermanos)

Tags: science-based, economy, food, dinosaurs, farming

Assume we managed to revive the famed velociraptor. The real one, which is [the size of a turkey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/17729/could-a-human-ride-a-raptor), not the movie version.

How viable would it be to breed them for human consumption?

I've reviewed the questions about [raptors in the wild](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/100081/a-pack-of-velociraptors-in-a-modern-ecosystem-that-would-be-pretty-horrible-ri/100099#100099), and these relate to their general ability to find a niche, but not excel in it. In a farming environment... Chickens are probably the pinnacle at price per pound, but we do breed poultry sized from quail to ostriches.

So how well would velociraptors do at competing for a place on our tables, for eggs and for meat?

Answer (score 7):

The main issue that you will face is that, while the poultry we rise today are omnivores and can be fed with energetically cheap food like seeds and the like, rising a carnivore requires that you give them "meat", or more in general energy expensive food to get back food which is on the same level of energy value.

So, instead of concentrating cheap into expensive (grass into steak), you are giving expensive to get expensive (steak into steak).

Comment: +1 While I can feed my cat vegetable-based foods (and I've a local vet who's absolutely sure that wild animals would all be better as vegetarians), the reality is that my cat's metabolism and physiology wants protein-rich meats. And even though she's a little fluffy thing that has me wrapped around her littlest claw, the chopped up pork, beef, chicken, and fish she gets is a LOT more expensive than any grain-based diet - but substantially more healthy for her. The point is, we consume herd animals (that graze grass) and avoid apex predators (like my cat...) for many reasons. This is just one.

Comment: It's true, however there's a market for premium meat, so it could be viable.